# urlconnection javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, ubuntu, outputstream, urlconnection

im trying to use an UrlConnection to send audio (represented as a base64 byte array - as requested by the Google Cloud Speech API). I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi with ubuntu. The connection does work if I use it on my laptop (also with ubuntu). I am using java with an URLConnection. The crash happens on OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

Java Code:

```
// URL to google + parameter with the API key.
    URL googleUrl = new URL(GOOGLE_RECOGNIZER_URL + "?key=" + APIKEY);

    // Open New URL connection channel.
    URLConnection urlConnection;

    urlConnection = googleUrl.openConnection();

    // we want to do output. (input is automaticly set on true).
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    // No caching.
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Add headers.
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

// For sending the recorded data to google it needs to be first
    // converted to a byte array.
    byte[] array1 = AudioToByteArray.readAudioFileData(file);

    // And next convert the byte array to a base64 string.
    String audioString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array1);

    // Make (JSON) Strings for configuration and location of audio file.
    String testConfig = "\"config\": { \"encoding\":\"LINEAR16\", \"sampleRate\": 16000, \"languageCode\": \"nl-NL\"}";
    String testAudioLoc = "\"audio\": { \"content\": \"" + audioString + "\" }";
    String together = "{ " + testConfig + "," + testAudioLoc + " }";

    // Send the string to google.
    OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    wr.write(together);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    out.close();
```

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at main.ContactGoogleCloudSpeechAPI.writeOut(ContactGoogleCloudSpeechAPI.java:98)
at main.ContactGoogleCloudSpeechAPI.contactGoogleUrlCon(ContactGoogleCloudSpeechAPI.java:41)
at main.SpeechRecognition.contactAPI(SpeechRecognition.java:184)
at main.SpeechRecognition.mainLoop(SpeechRecognition.java:104)
at main.SpeechRecognition.run(SpeechRecognition.java:81)
at main.SpeechRecognition.main(SpeechRecognition.java:62)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167189/illegalstateexception-thrown-by-maven-ssl-related-when-downloading-project-de solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception, and realized that I was using openJDK

So the solution is to uninstall openJDK and install oracle JDK

You can check which JDK version are you using the following command:

```
java -version
```